# How can I prevent Doctrine from generating SQL for a specific table?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I have a huge table, that I want to use in Symfony/Doctrine, but I don't want Doctrine populating it every time I re-generate my table schemas, because it's huge, it takes too long to import, it wouldn't work well if I'd put it in the fixtures.

How can I define it's structure in Doctrine, generate it's data model for PHP, while preventing Doctrine from generating the database table schema?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Does it take long to create tables or load data from fixtures?

Comment: Loading the data if I would place it in the fixtures.

Comment: I suppose this table is a read only and you don't want to rebuild its classes and insert sql. If so, you can move this schema to a separate connection and only build classes in your 'doctrine' connection. Have a look at [my symfony fork](https://github.com/dziamid/Symfony_forked), where I implemented this. For example, you can run ./symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load --con='doctrine' and it will only affect classes for doctrine connection.

Answer (score 0):

Don't save that data into your fixtures and instead export it using mysqldump (or similar) and then import it afterwards (using normal SQL commands) eg.

`mysql -u user -p password database_name < data/massive_table_export.sql`

Comment: I have two problems with that: 1) even the raw mysql import is too slow 2) I want to define the table in the schema.yml

Comment: If the raw import is too slow then you're going to need to store it somewhere where symfony/doctrine doesn't destroy/rebuild it. Also, you *can* define the table in the schema, just don't export the table definition (or use `create if not exists`) when you dump it. In fact, this is exactly what I do. I also have a massive table that I use a couple of rows of dummy data for in my dev environment and use a script to choose whether to load in the full (slow) table, or the dummy (fast) table on build.